# How to use LIKE-operator on BigQuery TIMESTAMP fields

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query like

`SELECT Id,CreationDate From Orders WHERE CreationDate LIKE '2019-08-23%' ORDER BY CreationDate DESC LIMIT 5`

The error message I get is

> No matching signature for operator LIKE for argument types: TIMESTAMP, STRING. Supported signatures: STRING LIKE STRING; BYTES LIKE BYTES at [1:56]

How can I use the LIKE-operator on a TIMESTAMP-field in BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

The most optimal way is to use DATE function here `WHERE DATE(CreationDate) = '2019-08-23'`, as in below example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT Id,CreationDate
FROM `project.dataset.Orders`
WHERE DATE(CreationDate) = '2019-08-23' 
ORDER BY CreationDate DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use DATE functions that does this things. Either `date()` or between statements.

As timestamp is not a string, you should CAST to string

```
select CAST(timestamp as STRING)
```

Comment: Still get same error.. do I need to alter my WHERE-clause also?

Comment: yes, this goes in the where, or you can subquery the table as a wrapper